# Python/Flask - Error returning a .mp4 response

Tags: python, flask

I'm creating a proxy for aws s3. The client will request a video and the proxy will take this video from an s3 bucket and return the video to the user.

I'm doing it in python using flask - my code:

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request, Response
import requests, boto3
....

        headers = {
            'Content-type': 'video/mp4',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0'
        }        

        r = requests.get(url='https://faciso.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/small.mp4', stream=True)
    
        response = Response(r.raw, status=201, headers=headers, mimetype='video/mp4', content_type='video/mp4')

        return response
```

this code works in firefox browser:

[image]

but it doesn't work on google chrome!

[image]

the terminal when I try to open in google chrome:

[image]

**Can someone help me? I'm new to python and I've been trying to solve this problem for a few days.**